# Override class variables in production.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Beginner RoR programmer here.

Let's say I have something like:

```
class Foo
    cattr_accessor :VAR_ONE, :VAR_TWO

    # these need to be overridden in config/initializers/production.rb
    @@VAR_ONE = nil
    @@VAR_TWO = nil

    ...
```

How can I set those variables in *production.rb*? I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
class << Rails.application
    ...
end

class << Rails.foo
    VAR_ONE = ENV['VAR_ONE']
    VAR_TWO = ENV['VAR_TWO']
end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can test to see what environment you're in:

```
if Rails.env.production?  
 //do something
end
```

Also - if you're trying to save API keys or whatnot. You can set them seperately through the terminal, or in your secrets.yml, and specify the environment.

Answer (score 0):

No need to check for `production` in the code, delegate this kind of variables to environment.
Gem called `dotenv`: https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv. Simple as:

1. create `.env` file in the root dir
2. add variables: `VAR_ONE=1`
3. use them in the code `VAR_ONE = ENV['VAR_ONE']`